# How to properly use Application Insights in UWP, offline scenario

Tags: azure, mvvm, win-universal-app, uwp, azure-application-insights

In my UWP app I want to use Application Insights, but after many hours search for the best implementation, I don't know how to do it. 
I use MVVM Light, and in App.xaml.cs added below code:

```
WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync();
```

In the every ViewModel I have new instance of TelemetryClient. Everything looks great, but I have a problem with synchronization in offline scenario.

I assume that in this situation data should be stored in *AppData\Local\Microsoft\ApplicationInsights{appGuid}* or *AppData\Local\Packages{appGuid}\LocalState\ApplicationInsights* and then sync with Azure, but both localization are still empty. The same problem exist when I'm offline in release and debug mode.

What is your suggestion for me ?

Answer (score 0):

In you ViewModels, do you use the instance of TelemetryClient to send some data to the server (or to the cache, in offline mode) ?
Also, have you properly configured AppInsights ? Does it works when you are online ?

Edit: Does is happened in Release Mode or Debug Mode ? According to the doc:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-usage/

> Debug
>
> If you build in debug mode, events are sent as soon as they are
>   generated. If you lose internet connectivity and then exit the app
>   before regaining connectivity, offline telemetry is discarded.

Comment: In ViewModels I send data to the server and it works fine when I'm online. The problem is in offline mode. I tried use **PersistenceChannel**, but in my case it didn't resolve problem. I used of course Flush() before suspend app.

Comment: I tried this: release mode and offline -> send data -> in VS suspend and shut down -> in OnSuspending in App.xaml.cs telemetryClient.Flush(). As result nothing save locally and then send to server